# Parse a 2D array from input in Common Lisp

Tags: multidimensional-array, common-lisp

So I'm trying to parse a 2D array from standard input into a data structure in Common Lisp (SBCL). 
I expect the input to be of the form

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

if it has 3 rows.

So far I've gotten this:

```
(defun read-2d-array (rows &rest args)
    (values (read-from-string
             (concatenate 'string "#2A("
                          (dotimes (i rows)
                            (concatenate 'string "("
                                         (apply #'read-line args)
                                         ")"))
                          ")"))))
```

The problem with this is that while the outer concatenate seems to work, I'm having trouble trying to concatenate across the loop iterations and get the form:

```
#2A((1 2 3)(4 5 6)(7 8 9))
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this concatenating is not the best approach.

Common Lisp can read and print using strings.

**Just print to a string output stream, created by `WITH-OUTPUT-TO-STRING`**:

```
(defun convert-text-to-array-string (stream)
  (with-output-to-string (out-stream)
    (write-string "#2A(" out-stream)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil nil)
          while line
          do
          (write-string "("  out-stream)
          (write-string line out-stream)
          (write-string ")"  out-stream))
    (write-string ")"  out-stream)))
```

When returning from `WITH-OUTPUT-TO-STRING`, the form returns the string resulting from the output done to the stream.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to parse the invidual numbers with `PARSE-INTEGER` and put them into an array yourself, rather than making a string and reading a literal array out of it.

```
(defun read-2d-array (rows &rest args)
  ;; I'm assuming that the array is a square matrix. Otherwise you'd
  ;; need the number of columns too.
  (let ((arr (make-array (list rows rows) 
                         :element-type 'integer
                         :initial-element 0)))
    (dotimes (i rows)
      (let ((line (apply #'read-line args))
            (start 0))
        (dotimes (j rows)
          (multiple-value-bind (number end)
              (parse-integer line :start start
                                  :junk-allowed t)
            (setf start end
                  (aref arr i j) number)))))
    arr))

(with-input-from-string (str "1 2 3
4 50 6
7 8 9")
  (read-2d-array 3 str))
;=> #2A((1 2 3) (4 50 6) (7 8 9))
```

**Edit**

Just to be safe, here's a version that figures out the number of columns by looking at the first line of input.

```
(defun read-2d-array (rows &rest args)
  (let* ((first-line (apply #'read-line args))
         (cols (1+ (count #\space first-line)))
         (arr (make-array (list rows cols)
                          :element-type 'integer
                          :initial-element 0)))
    (loop for i below rows
          for line = first-line then (apply #'read-line args)
          for start = 0
          do (dotimes (j cols)
               (multiple-value-bind (number end)
                   (parse-integer line :start start
                                       :junk-allowed t)
                 (setf start end
                       (aref arr i j) number))))
    arr))
```

Or using CL-PPCRE to extract integers from the line:

```
(defun read-2d-array (rows &rest args)
  (labels ((numbers (string)
             (mapcar #'parse-integer
                     (cl-ppcre:all-matches-as-strings "\\d+" string))))
    (let* ((first-line (numbers (apply #'read-line args)))
           (cols (length first-line))
           (arr (make-array (list rows cols)
                            :element-type 'integer
                            :initial-element 0)))
      (loop for i below rows
            for line = first-line then (numbers (apply #'read-line args))
            do (dotimes (j cols)
                 (setf (aref arr i j) (pop line))))
      arr)))
```

Comment: I don't think that knowing the number of rows and columns in advance is implied by the question?

Comment: @BRPocock The function in the question does have `rows` as an argument. Since the example input was a square, I figured it would be safe to assume that the number columns would the same (or at least known).

Comment: Just guessing that the OP might be looking for something like a generic"CSV" reader, but definitely not specified in question

Answer (score 0):

Your [`dotimes`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dotime.htm) form returns `nil`.

You need to concatenate the lines you read:

```
(defun read-2d-array (rows &rest args)
  (values (read-from-string
           (concatenate 'string "#2A("
                        (apply #'concatenate 'string
                               (loop :repeat rows
                                 :collect (apply #'read-line args)))
                        ")"))))
```